# Select Only Rows with One Occurence of an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Database Tables that looks like this:

```
Knowledge
id          |        Title
--------------------------
3                     Hi
6                     Hello
7                     Yo
5                     Jump


Sorting
id          +        kID       
--------------------------
0           |         3
1           |         6
2           |         7
3           |         6
4           |         7
5           |         5
```

I'm trying to select Only Rows from the `Sorting` table that have a single occurence of the kID, and this is what I tried:

```
SELECT Knowledge.*, Sorting.*
FROM Knowledge, Sorting 
WHERE Knowledge.id = Sorting.KID
GROUP BY Sorting.KID 
    HAVING COUNT(Sorting.KID)<2
ORDER BY Sorting.SortOrder
LIMIT 0,8
```

For some reason it still returns everything instead of just `Hi` and `Jump` which is what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: . . Are you sure that is the query you are running?  It looks okay to me, but I notice that it uses a column that is not in the sample data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I can't find anything wrong with it, also I left off the Sort Order column for simplicity.

Comment: Just remembered I left the Sorting table in the query to show why I was combining the tables in the first place.

Comment: @Talon what are you expecting the result to be?  See this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ab89/5 -- it returns the `hi` and `jump`

Comment: @bluefeet yeah, your example worked perfectly! I'm not sure why, i'll have to read up on inner Join's.  Not sure why mine doesn't work, but yours seems to work great.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Talon I added my comment as an answer since you stated that it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a subquery to get the result:

```
select k.id, k.title
from knowledge k
inner join
(
  select kID
  from sorting
  group by kID
  having count(kID) < 2
) s
  on k.id = s.kid
LIMIT 0,8;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ab89/5).

The subquery will return only those rows that have the single count in the `sorting` table, then you can use this result to join to `knowledge` table.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Knowledge.*, Sorting.*
FROM Knowledge, Sorting 
WHERE Knowledge.id = Sorting.KID
group by kID
having count(id) < 2
```

The problem was you were doing count() on the wrong field

Comment: Your query doesn't even reference `Knowledge` table, so is at best incomplete and at worst just wrong.  I believe it's the latter.

Comment: @MadBreaks Are you happy? All I did was add the join back in from the original query, which is something any programmer can do on their own :P